# How to copy all rows from one column that contains two specific values to a different sheet on Excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to copy all rows from an excel sheet (Sheet1) that have a specific value that is referenced from a different cell. and then paste them into a new sheet(Sheet2).
My specific example is I have figured out that I want to copy the rows that have a '0' and/or '35' in column A. these values can change however due to what ever is in "B6" and "B7". 
The problem that I am having is it only copys rows that contain the value from "B6" which is 0 and ignoring my command that wants the "B7" value which is 35 in my instance. My code is below for reference

```
Sub Temp_copy()
set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
set e = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim d
Dim j
d = 1
j = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("A" & j))
If i.Range("A"&j) = Range("B6"&j) Then
d=d+1
e.Rows(d).Value=i.Rows(j).Value

End If

j = j+1
Loop

Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("A" & j))
If i.Range("A"&j) = Range("B7"&j) Then
d=d+1
e.Rows(d).Value=i.Rows(j).Value

End If

j = j+1
Loop

End Sub
```

I am new to VBA so any help or guidance to achieve what I need would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: `Range("B6"&j)` should be just `Range("B6")`  Similarly B7

Answer (score 0):

The simple `or` operator will help you get this done!

```
Sub Temp_copy()
Set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set e = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim d
Dim j
d = 1
j = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("A" & j))
    If i.Range("A" & j) = Range("$B$6") Or i.Range("A" & j) = Range("$B$7") Then
        d = d + 1
        e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value

    End If
j = j + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I have updated the code. This works on my system. Try it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through cells, you may use Autofilter to copy the desired data like below...

```
Sub CopyRows()
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set sws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set dws = Sheets("Sheet2")
lr = sws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
dws.Cells.Clear
sws.AutoFilterMode = False
'Assuming Row1 is the Header Row on Sheet1
With sws.Range("A1:A" & lr)
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=sws.Range("B6").Value, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=sws.Range("B7").Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
    dws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
sws.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```